# gettin ReferenceError: function is not defined while using ajax call - works fine without ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code (removed lot of code for brevity purpose)  in my index.html.

When I remove the Ajax call from the getConcepts function, I don't get any error and all the console logs statements shows up in the console.

However, when I try to call the getConcepts function with Ajax call, I keep getting

ReferenceError: getConcepts is not defined index.html:1:1  Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getConcepts() {



               console.log("Title of Research Project inside index.html");
               var project_title = $("#projectTitleId").val();
               console.log(project_title);

               console.log("Description of Research Project inside index.html");
               var project_description = $("#descriptionId").val();
               console.log(project_description);

               var intendedUse = sessionStorage.getItem("selectedIntendedUse");
               console.log("Intended Use inside index.html");
               console.log(intendedUse);

               $.ajax({
                       type: "Post",
                       url: "http://localhost:8080/Datagetter/datagetter",
                       data:{
                          p_in_user_id: 'JACK',
                          p_in_user_application:'MyAPP',
                          personnel_id='12345'
                       },
                       async: true,
                       cache: false,
                       success: function(data) {

                           console.log("Inside success of datagetter endpoint");
                           console.log(data);


                       };
                   }​);​






           }
           else {

           }
       }
    }


</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="conceptsButton" onclick="getConcepts()">Request Data</button>
   </div>
   <!-- /#wrapper -->
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Updating my post with actual code (not including other JS libraries though).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/css/bootstrapvalidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/style.css"/>
 <link href="js/jquery.growl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    function getConcepts() {
        alert ("yo");
                   /*$.ajax({
                       type: "Post",
                       url: "http://localhost:8080/Datagetter/datagetter",
                       data:{
                          p_in_user_id: 'JACK',
                          p_in_user_application:'MyAPP',
                          personnel_id='12345'
                       },
                       async: true,
                       cache: false,
                       success: function(data) {

                           console.log("Inside success of datagetter endpoint");
                           console.log(data);


                       };
                   }​);​*/
     }  

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" >
               <img src="images/test.png" width = "210px" height = "50px"   >
              </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Top Menu Items -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">               
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <div class="row" id="main" >
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 well " style="padding:0px;"   id="content">
                    <h3>Data Getterr!</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- BEGIN Bootstrap form testing-->
               <form class="form-horizontal" id="validateForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return false">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
                            <!--<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Select your desk sets:</label>
                                <select id = "deskSetlist" name="deskSets" class="form-control" >
                                    <option value=" " >Please select desk set</option>
                                    <option value=" " >test1</option>
                                     <option value=" " >test2</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Description of research project:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control"  id = "descriptionId"name="descriptionOfResearchProject" placeholder="Enter your description here...."></textarea>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Title of your research project:</label>
                                <input id = "projectTitleId" name="titleOfResearchProject" placeholder="Enter your title here...." class="form-control" type="text">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Intended use:</label>
                                <select id="intendedUseList" name="intendedUse" class="form-control" >
                                    <option value=" " >Please select one</option>
                                    <option>First</option>
                                    <option>Second</option>
                                    <option>Third</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                         <!--<div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-success" id="conceptsButton" onclick="getConcepts()">Request Data</button>
                              </div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="smartSearchDisp" style= "margin-top: 25px;">
                        <p>A div for smart search!</p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="conceptsButton" onclick="getConcepts()">Request Data</button>
                    <!--<button class="btn btn-success" id="conceptsButton" >Request Data</button>-->
                    </form>
                <!-- END form testing-->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
</div><!-- /#wrapper -->
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/downloader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.growl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            //Initialize function when document 'is ready'
         $(document).ready(function() {
        //BEGIN FORM Validations
            $('#validateForm').bootstrapValidator({
          feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {

            deskSets: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please select a desk set'
                    }
                }
            },
            titleOfResearchProject: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Please Enter the title with minimum 5 letters length'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please Enter title of your project'
                    }
                }
            },

            descriptionOfResearchProject: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 15,
                        max: 100,
                        message: 'Please enter at least 15 characters and no more than 100'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please Enter Description'
                    }
                }
            },
            intendedUse: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please select one option'
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });

            //END FORM Validations
    });
            //END FORM Validations
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows the alert button when I click on Request button and as soon as I include the Ajax call related code, I keep getting `ReferenceError: getConcepts is not defined index.html:1:1`

Comment: It might be easier find the problem if you post both (working and not working) versions of your code.

Comment: Your `data` assignment of `personnel_id` is incorrect due to the `=`. A semicolon too much after `success` and the whole `else` part messes up your function closure (there is not starting to the `}` before the else). Just open the console and you will find all errors.

Comment: I suspect that something else in your script is failing or not allowing the `getConcepts()` definition to be loaded. The error suggests it does not exists.

Comment: Your script appears to have syntax errors, which will cause the script to be unparseable. You have a bunch of braces and else statement after your code that don't match anything.

Comment: I updated my post with actual code. Please take a look. It's not erroneous anymore. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of Syntax errors in your code. These must be corrected. I would also suggest moving away from `onClick` attribute and retain all your code in your jQuery block. Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  function getConcepts() {
    console.log("Title of Research Project inside index.html");
    var project_title = $("#projectTitleId").val();
    console.log(project_title);

    console.log("Description of Research Project inside index.html");
    var project_description = $("#descriptionId").val();
    console.log(project_description);

    var intendedUse = sessionStorage.getItem("selectedIntendedUse");
    console.log("Intended Use inside index.html");
    console.log(intendedUse);

    $.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/Datagetter/datagetter",
      data: {
        p_in_user_id: 'JACK',
        p_in_user_application: 'MyAPP',
        personnel_id: '12345'
      },
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Inside success of datagetter endpoint");
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }

  $("#conceptsButton").click(getConcepts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="conceptsButton">Request Data</button>
</div>
```

**Update**

Your updated code still has Syntax errors. You may want to make use of jshint.com to help you find errors.

```js
$(function() {
  function getConcepts() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/Datagetter/datagetter",
      data: {
        p_in_user_id: 'JACK',
        p_in_user_application: 'MyAPP',
        personnel_id: '12345'
      },
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Inside success of datagetter endpoint");
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }

  $("#conceptsButton").click(getConcepts);

  //BEGIN FORM Validations
  $('#validateForm').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      deskSets: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please select a desk set'
          }
        }
      },
      titleOfResearchProject: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 5,
            message: 'Please Enter the title with minimum 5 letters length'
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please Enter title of your project'
          }
        }
      },
      descriptionOfResearchProject: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 15,
            max: 100,
            message: 'Please enter at least 15 characters and no more than 100'
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please Enter Description'
          }
        }
      },
      intendedUse: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please select one option'
          }
        }
      },
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/css/bootstrapvalidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="images/test.png" width="210px" height="50px">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Top Menu Items -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Page Heading -->
      <div class="row" id="main">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 well " style="padding:0px;" id="content">
          <h3>Data Getterr!</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- BEGIN Bootstrap form testing-->
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="validateForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return false">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Description of research project:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="descriptionId" name="descriptionOfResearchProject" placeholder="Enter your description here...."></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Title of your research project:</label>
                <input id="projectTitleId" name="titleOfResearchProject" placeholder="Enter your title here...." class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Intended use:</label>
                <select id="intendedUseList" name="intendedUse" class="form-control">
                  <option value=" ">Please select one</option>
                  <option>First</option>
                  <option>Second</option>
                  <option>Third</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" id="smartSearchDisp" style="margin-top: 25px;">
            <p>A div for smart search!</p>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-success" id="conceptsButton">Request Data</button>
        </form>
        <!-- END form testing-->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at my actual code please? I removed everything from the function for testing except an alert and ajax call and tested and it still throws same error.

I tried moving away from onClick (not shown above) and for some reason it didn't do anything. Before I try this, I want to figure out that error with Ajax call first. Thanks!

Comment: @Tan added update. You still have a lot of syntax issues in your code. I corrected those, again. I am unable to test fully.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm going to test it fully now and see how it goes. Appreciated.